Why would the saints need the River of Life when they are raised immortal?
There is a River of Life that flows out from the Throne of God in the midst of paradise where the saints are headed and on either side of that river is the tree of life yielding fruits every month. Why would the saints need a River of Life if our bodies are resurrected immortal?
This is a verse I picked up from the Pauline letters concerning the resurrection of the dead and it says both the wicked and the righteous are raised immortal.
1 Corinthians 15:53

"For this perishable body must put on the imperishable, and this mortal body must put on immortality"

But in the Book of Revelation there is the paradise of God which Jesus promised the saints, there is a River that proceeds from the Throne of God with trees on either side yielding eternal fruit, I understand this water perpetuates the eternity of the saints into the future and their healing.
Revelation 22:1

And he showed me a pure river of water of life, clear as crystal, proceeding from the throne of God and of the Lamb. 2 In the middle of its street, and on either side of the river, was the tree of life, which bore twelve fruits, each tree yielding its fruit every month. The leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations. Revelation 22:1-2

Why would the saints need that when they have already been raised immortal?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The question is a reflection on the relationship between 1 Corinthians 15:53 (the bodies of the saints are raised immortal) and Revelation 22:1 (the river of life flowing from God's throne). The questioner asks: Why would the saints need a River of Life if our bodies are resurrected immortal?
My brief answer (in my first comment above) was:

The river of life is simply a poetic/pictorial statement of the reality that God is the source of eternal life. Don't read it literally as something happening after resurrection according to historical time. Paul and John are saying the same thing but in different language.

For some people, this will be a sufficient answer. But the following comments showed that further explanation might be helpful. So here goes...
When we talk about God we need to think very carefully about our use of language. For example, suppose I said that every word describing God in the Bible is symbolic. I suspect some readers would have major problems with that word. But the reality is that the Christian God is eternal. He's immortal. He's infinite. He's everywhere. He's completely beyond the reach of our ordinary time-and-space-bound reality. He's also beyond the reach of the time-and-space-bound language we use to try and describe him.
Let me make that practical with some examples:

Rock

We all know what a rock is. It's that big stony thing I find in my garden or out in the fields. So when I read (in Exodus 17) that Moses struck the rock and water flowed out of it, I have a clear picture in my mind of the object that Moses struck.
But how do I handle the passage in Deuteronomy 32 which uses rock to describe God?

4 He is the Rock, his works are perfect, and all his ways are just.
15 They abandoned the God who made them and rejected the Rock their Savior.
18 You deserted the Rock, who fathered you; you forgot the God who gave you birth.

What does this mean? Surely none of us think that God is "that big stony thing I find in my garden."? Instead, Moses invites us to think the other way around. It's not that God is a rock. It's not even that God is like a rock. It's that a rock - yes, a small, pathetic metallic object in the back of my garden - is like God. We are invited to think about that little bit of creation and see in it something of the creator. A rock is strong. it is lasting. It is a good foundation material for building other things. And in these ways, we get the smallest, briefest hint of who God is and what he is like. He is all that is good in that rock, only a million, billion, gazillion times more so.
You might say to me, "Then why don't we use those other words to describe God? Why don't we just say that he is strong and lasting and a stable foundation for our lives?" And of course, we can do that. But take a moment to read again that last sentence. Try to find in it a word that is not drawn from our earthbound experience. Strong. Lasting. Stable. Foundation. These too are human words trying to say something about God, but never fully succeeding, never doing God justice. They are true words, but they are never the full story, because God is always more than.

Heaven.

This word gets closer to our original question, and so has the potential to be more controversial. But I would humbly argue that everything I've said about Rock is also true about Heaven. This is a word with a natural physical meaning, but then put to use as a true but partial description of God's dwelling place. (And note that dwelling place suffers exactly the same limitation: A human expression trying to do a superhuman job.)
The natural meaning of heaven is "What we see when we look up: the sky and all that it contains." Psalm 19 is a good example.

The heavens declare the glory of God; the skies proclaim the work of his hands.
[The sun] rises at one end of the heavens and makes its circuit to the other.

"The heavens and the earth" is often heard and read in the bible, and that phrase has a wider meaning. The "high and low" contrast is the writer's way of describing all of creation. In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth means that God created everything; creation as a whole package is being described. But still, the word heaven is being used naturally: from the physical heavens above to the physical earth below, God made it all.
But then we find texts where heaven is a specific location for God:
Matthew 6:9

Our Father in heaven, hallowed be your name.

Psalm 53:2

God looks down from heaven on all mankind to see if there are any who understand, any who seek God.

2 Chronicles 6:32

[When people come] and pray toward this temple, then hear from heaven, your dwelling place.

The Chronicles example is particularly interesting. The setting is Solomon's prayer to God as he dedicates the temple, inviting God to come and dwell there. But despite this prayer, he explicitly recognises that it is impossible for God to be contained by anything inside of the physical creation:
2 Chronicles 2:5-6

The temple I am going to build will be great, because our God is greater than all other gods. But who is able to build a temple for him, since the heavens, even the highest heavens, cannot contain him? Who then am I to build a temple for him, except as a place to burn sacrifices before him?

How do we connect these ideas? I suggest that when it comes to describing the location of God, the writers of the Bible texts knew full well that God doesn't actually live in one particular place. God is far more than his creation. God is not limited by his creation. But all our language is limited to our own time and space. So again, when we talk about God, we do it with words that at best are partial, trying to find comparisons that get the basic ideas across.
And that's why heaven is so often chosen as the word to describe God's dwelling place. Heaven is chosen because it is big. If I told you that God lived in a shoe box under my bed, you would just laugh at me. But "God in heaven" at least makes sense, because heaven is the biggest comparison we can find. Thinking of heaven at least forces us to look upwards, which is the right attitude towards God.
So to summarise, I believe that every time the word heaven is used to describe a place where God lives, it's not being used physically, but comparatively: God's home (again an earthbound word, but what choice do we have?) is far greater than our universe, so the best we can do is choose language from our experience that at least provides a hint of where God truly is.

The river of life

I hope anyone who has read this far will understand my approach here. John is describing a reality about God. His description is definitely true; I don't want anyone to assume that I am questioning the truth element. But it's also true that he is describing spiritual realities with physical words, so his true statements at best are partial. Flowing water points to God's Spirit; but the Spirit of God is far, far greater than the flowing water. Trees constantly in fruit point to eternal life; but our experience of eternal life will be far greater and deeper than any tree picture can communicate. And so on.
Note that John sees these things as pictures. This idea of seeing should not lead us back to thinking literally or physically. John's seeing is in the Spirit. All his descriptions by definition are his attempt to create human word pictures to explain the spiritual realities he sees. We need to respect John's word pictures by reading them the same way. I actually imagine finally arriving in heaven and thinking, "Dear John, you tried your best but this is so magnificent that you didn't have a chance of getting the true picture across!"

1 Corinthians 15:12-13 says:

But if it is preached that Christ has been raised (egēgertai) from the
dead, how can some of you say that there is no resurrection
(anastasis) of the dead? If there is no resurrection (anastasis) of
the dead, then not even Christ has been raised (egēgertai).

John 5:28-29 says:

Do not be amazed at this, for a time is coming when all who are in
their graves will hear his voice and come out—those who have done what
is good will rise (anastasin) to live (zōēs), and those who have done what is evil will
rise (anastasin) to be condemned (kriseōs).

Revelation 22:1-2 say:

And he showed me a pure river of water of life (zōēs), clear as crystal, proceeding from the throne of God and of the Lamb. In the middle of
its street, and on either side of the river, was the tree of life (zōēs),
which bore twelve fruits, each tree yielding its fruit every month. The leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations.

Revelation 21:4 says:

He will wipe every tear from their eyes. There will be no more death (thanatos; nominative masculine singular)
or mourning or crying or pain, for the old order of things has passed
away.

1 Corinthians 15:53 says:

For the perishable must clothe itself with the imperishable, and the
mortal (thnēton) with immortality (athanasian; accusative feminine singular).


Athanasian (adj.) from athanatos "immortal,"
from a- "not, without" (see a- (3)) + thanatos "death"

1 Corinthians 15:33 says:

Do not be misled: “Bad company corrupts good character.” Come back to
your senses as you ought, and stop sinning; for there are some who are
ignorant of God — I say this to your shame.

1 Corinthians 15:56 concludes:

The sting of death (thanatou) is sin and the power of sin is the law. But thanks be to God! He gives us the victory through our Lord Jesus Christ.

In addition, 1 Corinthians 15:22 says:

For as in Adam all die, so in Christ all will be made alive.

Genesis 2:16-17 says:

And the Lord God commanded the man, “You are free to eat from any tree
in the garden; but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge
of good and evil, for when you eat from it you will certainly die.”

Genesis 3:23-24 concludes:

So the Lord God banished him [Adam] from the Garden of Eden to work
the ground from which he had been taken.  After he drove the man out,
he placed on the east side of the Garden of Eden cherubim and a
flaming sword flashing back and forth to guard the way to the tree of
life.

In conclusion, both 1 Corinthians 15 and John 5:29 do not appear to say the wicked will be raised immortal. It appears only those (saints) who give up the sin of Adam (i.e., give up eating from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil) will be raised to Immortality with the Water & Tree of Life.
